# How to create mysql function in aws?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

- I tried creating a mysql stored procedures, it was okay. I tried to create  a function of mysql stored function but I am having this error.
- Did some research but was afraid to try because there were a lot of solution. I don't know which one is real.
- I tried also checking the privilege in phpmyadmin side. Not working.
- I also tried updating `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to 1 and caused an error. below is the image attached with error.
  [image]

**This is the error when I tried creating a function in aws server via phpmyadmin:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you need to set  `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to `1` in the RDS parameter group.

It is not "less safe" in a meaningful sense in RDS.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators

Comment: i will try this out

Comment: when I tried to update it... its causing another error `Error saving: Cannot modify a default parameter group. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 9c091359-7a3b-4da8-88ac-0fc919e2237c)`

Comment: turns out that the default parameter group is the default and cannot be edited or modified, it literally explains everything in the error. I created my own parameter with login_bin set to 1 and then replace the param group into my own param group and then made a reboot. It works fine! thank you very much!

Comment: @ichimaru Excellent.  Here's a bonus tip: always use a custom parameter group on RDS, even if you don't know of a specific reason why you need one.  Changing the parameter group associated with an instance always requires a reboot.  Changing many of the parameters within an existing group can be done without the reboot.